# Subsonic 3 - sp.ExcuteTypeList<T>() - sql_variant to varchar is not allowed

Tags: subsonic

I'm running subsonic 3 
when trying to call a stored procedure ( sp.ExecuteTypedList() ) I get the error :

> Implicit conversion from data type
>   sql_variant to varchar is not allowed.
>   Use the CONVERT function to run this
>   query.

Any idea on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's a bug. I logged an issue last night: http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues#issue/29

Comment: The ticket was just updated by Rob to say it's fixed. I haven't tested yet though.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this today - will have a push in the next few days.

Answer (score 2):

In the mean time here is a solution from John's suggestion

in StoredProcedures.tt

change the line

```
sp.Command.AddParameter("<#=par.Name#>",<#=par.Name#>);
```

to

```
sp.Command.AddParameter("<#=par.Name#>",<#=par.Name#>, DbType.<#= GetDbType(par.SysType)#>);
```